# Getting BigQuery results for a specific GH repository

Tags: github, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get all timestamped repo contributions (with contributor names) for a specific repo.

Let's say it's this one: `https://github.com/morucci/repoxplorer`

I've been playing around with the GH archive at BigQuery, but this is new to me, and it's not working.

This is the closest I've gotten:

```
/* count of issues opened, closed, and reopened on 2019/01/01 */
SELECT event as issue_status, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM (
  SELECT type, repo.name, actor.login,
    JSON_EXTRACT(payload, '$.action') as event, 
  FROM `githubarchive.day.20190101`
  WHERE type = 'IssuesEvent'
    AND repository_name = 'repoxplorer')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following VonC's answer, I figured out how to use `mergestat` to get a list of a specified repo's commits, with committer name and timestamp of every commit.

I used this query code:

```
-- MergeStat is a tool for running SQL queries on data in git repos:
-- https://github.com/mergestat/mergestat
    
SELECT author_name, author_when, committer_when, count(*)
FROM commits('https://github.com/mergestat/mergestat')
WHERE parents < 2 -- ignore merge commits
GROUP BY author_when ORDER BY author_when DESC
```

I suspect that there are better ways of getting the desired output, but adding this answer until a better solution is found.

Edit:

Running `mergestat` locally from the terminal I can generate the list I want using the following command:

```
mergestat "SELECT author_name, author_when, committer_when, count(*) FROM commits('https://github.com/mergestat/mergestat') WHERE parents < 2 GROUP BY author_when ORDER BY author_when DESC" -v >> output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is to:

- clone the repository
- use a static tool like

  - [`mergestat/mergestat`](https://github.com/mergestat/mergestat)

    ```
     SELECT count(*), author_name FROM commits GOUP BY author_name ORDER BY count(*) desc
    ```

    [image: https://github.com/mergestat/mergestat/raw/main/docs/cli-query-example.png]
  - [`irevenko/octotui`](https://github.com/irevenko/octotui)

> if James committed three times, I'd like to know the timestamp for all of his three commits.

```
git log --author="James" --format="%h %as %s" --all --branches
```

Comment: That looks great but I need timestamps for each contribution!

Comment: @Kasi You can add timestamp to the query, but not for a GitHub event like push. Only commits.

Comment: Oh that's great! Can you update your code so I can see how it's done?

Comment: @Kasi It depends on what you mean by "timestamp": most recent commit done by an author?

Comment: Ideally I'd get a list of all commits, where every commit has an author name and timestamp.

Comment: E.g., if James committed three times, I'd like to know the timestamp for all of his three commits.

Comment: @Kasi Then no need for fancy third-party tools: `git log --author="an author" --format="%h %as %s"` is enough

Comment: Ah, but I'm looking at repos with hundreds of contributors!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245919/discussion-between-vonc-and-kasi).